# Churn Prediction problem

Tags: regression, prediction, churn

I am a data science neophyte struggling to solve a churn prediction problem, i would be grateful to have someone help with the regression model

Comment: Welcome to the site! What help do you need exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have two datasets (train and test files) and need to predict customers that will likely churn. I believe solving this problem will help me understand how to solve similar problems and encourage me to continue my journey through Data Science

Answer (score 2):

I really like [this article](https://ragulpr.github.io/2016/12/22/WTTE-RNN-Hackless-churn-modeling/) because it gives an overview of common approaches to churn prediction as well as a new state-of-the-art method.  There is also code available. However, the state-of-the-art method uses a custom loss function built on top of recurrent neural nets, which is a complex place to dive in.